# Read Java DataOutputStream in C++ client

Tags: java, c++, sockets, boost-asio, dataoutputstream

All welcome.

Still trying to create a video straming'a (client-server-client) application.

The bottom line:

There are 2 clients. 1 - the sender, 2 - the recipient.

1 sends the size of the picture, the picture itself. The server receives and sends it first to the size of the picture, and then the picture itself, to another client.

For a C ++ socket, I use BOOST :: Asio.

There was such a problem:

I need in C ++ to first get the size of the image that sends Java, and then write the image itself into mass bytes.

When reading the image by Java DataInputStream (on the server side) - no problems arise.

But if I try to get Java server images in C ++, there is a huge problem, in the form that I don’t even know what the server sends.

What he sends specifically:

[image]

As I noticed here, C ++ still produces the symbol of the beginning of reading the image size and the symbol of the end of the image size:

[image]

Here Java sends them:

[image]

How can I get the size of the resulting image, and then write the entire image, for example, in byte[IMG_SIZE]?

Something like this:

```
int IMAGE_SIZE = SOCKET.READ_SOMETHING...

byte[IMAGE_SIZE] img = ??....
```

Java code:

```
private void ReadImage(){

        while (true) {
            try {
                int token = is.readInt();
                if (token == 4) {
                    dos.writeInt(4);
                    if (is.readUTF().equals("#@@#")) {

                        dos.writeUTF("#@@#");

                        int imgLength = is.readInt();

                        is.readUTF();

                        listener.onDataReceived(imgLength);

                        dos.writeInt(imgLength);
                        dos.writeUTF("-@@-");
                        dos.flush();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[imgLength];
                        int len = 0;
                        while (len < imgLength) {
                            len += is.read(buffer, len, imgLength - len);
                        }
                        dos.write(buffer);
                        dos.flush();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    ReconnectSockets();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

C++ Code:

```
void DataManager::ReadData()
{
    boost::array<char, 40000> buf;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

    string data(buf.begin(), buf.end());

    cout << data << endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: *I need in C ++ to first get the size of the image that sends Java, and then write the image itself into mass bytes.* No you don't. You could, for example, read small chunks and append them to a resizable buffer like `std::vector` until the java side stops sending and closes the connection.

Comment: But if you want to presize the buffer, have java send the size of the buffer required before sending the data you need to buffer. Note that you can't count on being able to read the entire buffer in one socket read for a number of reasons. You're better off reading small chunks in a loop until you have the all of the data in the message.

Comment: Your C++ code is not even remotely close to doing what your Java code does to receive the image data. It is not even attempting to handle the `"#@@#"` strings being sent back and forth, or trying to read the image size that is sent before the image data is sent.

Comment: @user "*have java send the size of the buffer required before sending the data you need to buffer*" - that is exactly what is happening. The Java code provided clearly shows that an image is prefixed by a 4-byte token, then a modified-UTF8 string `"#@@#"`, then **a 4-byte image length**, then another modified-UTF8 string, then **the actual image data**.  The C++ code provided is not attempting to read those individual values, like the Java code does.

Comment: `dos.writeInt(imgLength);` Yup. There it is. My apologies.